# Why data returned with astrotomic/laravel-translatable have invalid language?

Tags: laravel, laravel-translatable

On   laravel 9 site I added    astrotomic/laravel-translatable and getting set of data I see a bit different results I expected
As I have 2 languages defined in config/translatable.php with default  'en' :

```
'locales' => [
    'en',
    'fr',
...
    'locale' => 'en',
...
```

I do request with 'fr' locale:

```
$banners           = Banner
    ::translatedIn(app()->getLocale())
    ->get(function ($banner);
```

I check logs :

```
            [id] => 5
            [text] => laravel library site
            [description] => laravel is a powerful php library
            ...
            [translations] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 13
                            [text] => laravel library site
                            [description] => laravel is a powerful php library
                            ...
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 15
                            [text] => site de la bibliothèque laravel
                            [description] => laravel est une puissante bibliothèque php
                            ...
                        )

                )
```

)

Text in text, description fields(of banner, not translations] subarray...)  are in ‘en’, not in 'fr', as I expected...

In file app/Models/Banner.php I have :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;
use Astrotomic\Translatable\Contracts\Translatable as TranslatableContract;
use Astrotomic\Translatable\Translatable;

class Banner extends Model implements HasMedia, TranslatableContract
{
    use InteractsWithMedia;
    use Translatable;

    protected $table = 'banners';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [/*'text', 'description',*/ 'url', 'active', 'ordering', 'banner_bgimage_id', 'updated_at'];
    public $translatedAttributes = ['text', 'description'];

        "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "astrotomic/laravel-translatable": "^11.11",
```

and in app/Models/BannerTranslation.php :

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BannerTranslation extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['text', 'description', 'updated_at'];
}
```

Seems I did not miss any config options, but what is wrong ?

**ADDITIVE EXAMPLES:**

Looking at this docs :
https://docs.astrotomic.info/laravel-translatable/package/scopes#translatedin-string-usdlocale-null

I see some examples, like :

```
Post::translatedIn('en')->get();
```

and

```
$post = Post::first();
```

But example :

```
 $banner = Banner::first();
 $bannerText = $banner->translate('fr')->text;
```

also returns default value in ‘en’, not 'fr'

In my model
app/Models/Banner.php

I added :

```
protected $translationForeignKey = 'banner_id';
```

But it did not help and I got all text value in default  ‘en’.
I suppose I misconfigure something in my model definitions, but what ?

```
"astrotomic/laravel-translatable": "^11.11",
"laravel/framework": "^9.19",
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you're missing some code in your question. Nothing after `In file app/Models/Banner.php I have :`

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it

Comment: Pls, take a look at ADDITIVE EXAMPLES

Answer (score 0):

1. I found some strange for me decision as to work properly
   I need in file config/translatable.php to set

   'locale' => null,

and with this option then getting data as

```
$bannersInFrench = Banner
    ::translatedIn('fr')
    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

I got french labels.

2. Why I got ‘translations’ subarray in resulting list of data ? That is not really what I need...